# Scheme Function: (show-up-to-n '(4 6 3 -8 3 4) 5) ==> (4 3 -8 3 4)

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

i am trying to write a function in Scheme that takes in a list and an integer and outputs the same list minus all the members less than the integer... please help. I seem to be unable to add the numbers into a new list that can be outputed.

```
(define result '())

(display result)
(define nums-less-than-x
  (lambda (lst x) 
    (define impl
      (lambda (l1 b result) 
        (if (null? l1) result
            (begin (if (> b (car l1)) 
                       (begin (cons (car l1) result)
                              ;(display result)(newline)(newline)
                              (display (car l1) )(newline))

                       )
                   (impl (cdr l1) b result)
                   ))
        ))
    (impl lst x result)
    ))

(display (show-up  '(4 6 3 -8 3 4) 5))
```

The code juss displays `()`, an empty list like that, when I run

```
(display (num-less-than-x '(some list) x))
```

Comment: The code juss displays "()", an empty list like that when i run the (display (num-less-than-x '(some list) x)) function.

Comment: I think you mean "minus all the members *greater than* the integer".

Comment: What is the purpose of the `result` variable? You never update it. Did you mean to write `(set! result (cons (car l1) result))` to add the element to it?

Comment: Note that the variable `result` inside the `impl` function is not the same as the global variable.

Comment: What is `show-up`? Is that supposed to be `nums-less-than-x`?

Comment: Thank you! yes i had tried to fix that little typo with show-up but my browser was slow. @Barmar    But thank you, yes I needed to put "set" in there. I am really new, juss started scheme last night so i didn't even know about it.

Answer (score 0):

When programming in a functional style, we try to use existing procedures to solve a problem. With that in mind, the preferred solution would be:

```
(define (show-up-to-n lst x)
  (filter (lambda (n) (< n x))
          lst))
```

Also notice that in truly functional code we avoid at all costs procedures that modify state (such as `set!`), it's a better idea to create a new list with the result.

Answer (score 0):

Your `result` is never updated. usually I would expect that only when the element is *not* being a part of the result and otherwise a recursion like:

```
(impl (cdr l1) b (cons (car l1) result))
```

I notice that you have put debug output as the last expression in a `begin`, eg.

```
(begin
  expression-that-does-something
  (display ...)
  (newline))
```

Note that the expressions result is not the result, but the result from the `newline`, typically some undefined value. You need to put your debug stuff first then as the tail the expression your function should return. Alternatively you could make a debug function:

```
(define (debug expr)
  (display expr)
  (newline)
  expr))
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want the procedure to *return* the result, not to display it, which is the right way to do it:

```
(define show-up
  (lambda (lst mx)
    (if (null? lst)
        lst
        (let ((c (car lst)))
          (if (> c mx)
              (show-up (cdr lst) mx)
              (cons c (show-up (cdr lst) mx)))))))
```

Testing:

```
> (show-up  '(4 6 3 -8 3 4) 5)
'(4 3 -8 3 4)
```